# TRIGGER Oracle to prevent updating or inserting

Tags: oracle

I am having problems with this code below, which is a trigger used in Oracle SQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_TUTOR_BLOCK
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON tutors
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
BEGIN
   IF :new.tutorName = :old.tutorName
THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20101, 'A tutor with the same name currently exists.');
    ROLLBACK;
END IF;
END;
/
```

This trigger is used to prevent users from entering the same tutor name at different records.

After I insert two records with the same tutorname, the trigger does not block me from inserting it. Is there anyone can tell me what are the problems with this coding? Here are the sample format and insert values:

```
INSERT INTO tutors VALUES (tutorID, tutorName tutorPhone, tutorAddress, tutorRoom, loginID);


INSERT INTO tutors VALUES ('13SAS01273', 'Tian Wei Hao', '019-8611123','No91, Jalan Wangsa Mega 2, 53100 KL', 'A302', 'TianWH');
```

Answer (score 4):

Trigger in Kamil's example will throw [ORA-04091](http://ora-04091.ora-code.com/), you can see this with your own eyes [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/878e2/1). ROLLBACK in a trigger is unnecessary, it runs implicitly when a trigger makes a statement to fail.

You can prohibit any DML on table by [altering it with read only clause](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables006.htm#CJAGAFHJ):

```
alter table tutors read only;
```

At last, integrity should be declarated with [integrity constraints](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/data_int.htm#CNCPT1632) and not with triggers.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a trigger for this in Oracle.

You can do it with an "unique index" on the tutorName column (see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/indexes003.htm#i1106547).

Note: about your trigger, it fails on checking for another record with the same tutorName because it's not scanning the tutors table for another record with the same tutorName, it's just comparing the tutorName values of the row you are creating (in this case, old.tutorName is just NULL, because the row doesn't exist yet).

Comment: I see. Thanks. Is there any other way for me to use triggers to prevent any insertion or deletion using that table?

Comment: Add trigger BEFORE INSERT OR DELETE which always throws error and performs a rollback.

Answer (score 0):

Check the case in yours trigger body

```
IF :new.tutorName = :old.tutorName
```

It returns true only if 'tutorName' value is the same in new and old record. When you'll trying to updat some value you'll get

```
IF 'someTutorName' = 'someTutorName'
```

which will return TRUE.
Inserting row cannot fire this rule because you're trying to compare something like that:

```
'someTutorName' = NULL
```

This case always returns FALSE.
Try to use something like that

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_TUTOR_BLOCK
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON tutors
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    rowsCount INTEGER;
BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tutors WHERE tutorName is :new.tutorName INTO rowsCount;
   IF rowsCount > 0
THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20101, 'A tutor with the same name currently exists.');
    ROLLBACK;
END IF;
END;
/
```

But the best solution is the one mentioned by **friol** - use *unique index* by executing SQL like this

```
ALTER TABLE tutors
ADD CONSTRAINT UNIQUE_TUTOR_NAME UNIQUE (tutorName);
```

Comment: I don't think that will work in an update trigger as the row will be mutating

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna completely ignore recording a row to a table you can follow these steps

rename table to something else and create a view with the same name and create an instead of trigger.

```
create table usermessages (id number(10) not null)
GO

alter table usermessages rename to xusermessages
GO

create or replace view usermessages as (select * from xusermessages)
GO

create or replace trigger usermessages_instead_of_trg
  instead of insert or update on usermessages
  for each row
   begin
     Null ;
 end ;
GO

insert into usermessages(123)
```

Live test available here below

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ad6bc/2